# VBA: PasteSpecial from Excel to PowerPoint with "Shapes (unknown member): invalid request." error

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

This is part of my code, which pastes data from Excel to PowerPoint. Usually it works, but every once in a while (maybe after 10 or 20 runthroughs, each with about 15 `PasteSpecials` of the same type), I get an error: "Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable." The debugger points to the line `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2`. Can someone figure out why?

If you were to ask me why I'm using this data type, I can only say because it worked. I tried around and this one seemed to accurately copy what I saw in Excel to PowerPoint (others 'forgot' borders and the like).

```
Sub MReport()

    Dim rng As Range, rngAn As Range
    Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim DestinationPPT As String
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim wbM As Workbook
    Dim wsEm As Worksheet
    Dim CSGSheet As Variant, CSGSheets As Variant
    Dim MonthNum As String, YearNum As String

    Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    DestinationPPT = "C:\VBA\ReportTemplate.pptm"
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

    YearNum = "2019"
    MonthNum = "02"

    Set wbM = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA\" & YearNum & "\" & Right(YearNum, 2) & "_" & MonthNum & "\NumbersM_" & YearNum & "_" & MonthNum & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)

    CSGSheets = Array("CSG_BM", "CSG_AR", "CSG_ISF")

    For Each CSGSheet In CSGSheets
        lRow = wbM.Sheets(CSGSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lCol = wbM.Sheets(CSGSheet).Cells(lRow - 1, "B").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
        Set rng = wbM.Sheets(CSGSheet).Range(wbM.Sheets(CSGSheet).Cells(2, 2), wbM.Sheets(CSGSheet).Cells(lRow, lCol))
        rng.Copy
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12)
        PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

        With myShape
          .Height = 410
          .Top = 70
          .Left = 5
        End With
    Next

    wbM.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: can you check that the clipboard isn't empty when the error occurs ? [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Shapes.PasteSpecial) it says `An error occurs if there is no data on the Clipboard when the PasteSpecial method is called.`

Comment: see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613119/vba-office2010-shapes-pastespecial-fails) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186146/pastespecial-of-object-shapes-failed-vba)

Comment: @reportgunner I copied some code to determine if the clipboard is empty, we'll see if that's the issue. The links in your second comment should be really helpful; either I'll simply add a wait command or try the `Select` 
 and `Selection.Copy` method (although I don't understand why the latter would help). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I believe that the `DoEvents` bit is the magic in the second one. It did happen to me in the past that copying took ~2 seconds but my code was not waiting for these 2 seconds and ended up trying to paste before clipboard got filled up.

Comment: @reportgunner What exactly does Do Events do? I've read that it "temporarily pauses" the macro, but how short or long is "temporary"? Does this depend on the procedure you're running? What's the benefit vs `Application.Wait?`

Comment: `DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue and all keys in the SendKeys queue have been sent.`

pretty much waiting for the copy to finish.

Comment: @reportgunner Just as I wrote this, the error finally occurred again. Took about 50 loops of my whole sub (I'm guessing just checking for this before pasting gave Office more time and made the error occur less often), but it appears the clipboard being empty is indeed the issue.